# Possible to remap CapsLock with modifier functionality?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I want the Caps Lock key to be left parenthesis, as in (, and right shift + Caps Lock to be right parenthesis, as in ).

Is this possible in OS X?  Seil (https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en) doesn't seem to be able to do this.

I tried using Seil to map to a garbage key code, and then using Karibiner to map from that key code to another, but it didn't work.  Tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en) to map caps lock to some key like F19. Then install [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en) and save a file like this as `~/Library/Application Support/Karabiner/private.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>custom</name>
    <identifier>custom</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::KEY_9, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19, VK_SHIFT, KeyCode::KEY_0, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then open the Karabiner application, press the ReloadXML button, and click the checkbox for the setting.

If others search for how to for example map pressing caps lock to escape and holding caps lock to control, use `KeyOverlaidModifier`:

```
__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::F19, KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE
```

Comment: Works great.  Just one thing: In Karibiner remember to turn OFF the Programmer Settings "When pressed alone, Left Shift types left paren ( etc."  Otherwise, you just get 9 and 0 instead of ( and ).

Comment: Any idea why CapsLock in this configuration is 'slower' than on the internal keyboard?  I have to hold it down for about a tenth of a second for it to register.  On the internal keyboard it's just fine (this is with Apple chiclet style external keyboard).

Comment: "If you are using Seil to change the behavior of caps lock, open "System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys..." and change caps lock configuration to "No Action".

You need to do this step to to reduce caps lock delay." as per Step 3 here : https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en